# Enable anypoint service registry

Tags: mule

I'm getting following error when i try to run mule project

anypoint service registry agent is disabled

i was trying to enable this but couldn't find exact position.Please help me to enable  any point service agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Anypoint Studio are you using ? I recommend you to download the latest version, which is 5.0.

The Service Registry was a product that I believe it's not supported anymore. You can configure your Service Registry credentials from the preference pane under the Anypoint Studio category, but as I said this is an old product and it is not supported anymore in latest versions.

Other thing that could happened is that, if by any chance you tried to install a different ESB runtime in your Studio and if you didn't used the update site URL that comes by default and you added an old URL and installed the runtime, this runtime could be lacking the agent that Studio uses to run the ESB. Just guessing..

But just in case, please try to download the latest Studio

http://www.mulesoft.com/platform/mule-studio

Answer (score 0):

Anypoint Service Registry is currently a discontinued product. It was replaced by [Anypoint API Platform](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/), which has most of the capabilities of the previous product, plus more policies, improved analytics, integration with RAML, etc.